# Convert JSInterop's ExampleJsInterop JavaScript code to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm new to `.NetCore Blazor` and trying to convert ExampleJsInterop `JavaScript` code to `TypeScript`.
I have a problem with converting the code below:

```
window.exampleJsFunctions = {
  showPrompt: function (text) {
    return prompt(text, 'Type your name here');
  },
  displayWelcome: function (welcomeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('welcome').innerText = welcomeMessage;
  },
  returnArrayAsyncJs: function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorSample', 'ReturnArrayAsync')
      .then(data => {
        data.push(4);
          console.log(data);
    });
  },
  sayHello: function (dotnetHelper) {
    return dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SayHello')
      .then(r => console.log(r));
  }
};
```

Well, of course, there is no problem to convert the first two functions and the last one, but I can not convert the 3rd function since the `DotNet` is not valid on TypeScript:

```
returnArrayAsyncJs: function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorSample', 'ReturnArrayAsync')
      .then(data => {
        data.push(4);
          console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

My question is first of all, how can I convert this `JS` function to `TS`. and also that would be helpful if someone helps me to understand where this `DotNet` comes from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cheat method: add "declare var DotNet: any;" without the quotes to the top of the ts file. Otherwise one would normally find the definitely typed definitions, but I'm not sure if these exist for blazor yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where this DotNet comes from

Generally speaking, `DotNet`comes from the `JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop.JS` single file (See [Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop.JS/src/src/Microsoft.JSInterop.ts)). This file is imported in the `blazor.server.js`. And you'll reference this `blazor.server.js` script in your `Pages/_Host.csthml`:

```
<body>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="/built/exampleJsInterop.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the `blazor.server.js` is loaded at runtime , a global `DotNet` is created.

You can search the string `window.DotNet=` in the `blazor.server.js` to confirm. Since the `DotNet` is attached as a property of `window`, it becomes a **global** variable in your browser.

> how can I convert this JS function to TS.

Microsoft has not yet released an official `.d.ts` package for the `Microsoft.JsInterop` library. See https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1452

There's a `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dotnet/jsinterop` on the npmjs.com. But be careful as it seems **NOT an official release** (Not Sure).

One safe way, as suggested by [@SteveSandersonMS in above links](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1452#issuecomment-423205165), is to generate the `d.ts` by our own:

1. Copy the file and save it as `Microsoft.JsInterop.ts`: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop.JS/src/src/Microsoft.JSInterop.ts
2. Run `tsc --declaration` and get the `Microsoft.JsInterop.d.ts` file, save it in the path `wwwroot/@types/Microsoft.JsInterop.d.ts`.
3. Within your `exampleJsInterop.ts` file, let's say its path is `wwwroot/ts/exampleJsInterop.ts`, just add a declaration reference `/// <reference types="../@types/Microsoft.JsInterop" />` at the first line:

   ```
   └───wwwroot/
       ├───@types/
       |   |─── Microsoft.JsInterop.d.ts
       ├───built/
       └───ts/
           |─── exampleJsInterop.ts
   ```

   Now you can enjoy the typescript features from the `DotNet` module. See intellisense:
   [image: intellisense]

   By the way, I also change the `data => {data.push(4);... }`  to `(data: Number[])=> {... }`

Comment: Although I got a Rank down by someone ;), this answer is the exact clarification for my question and it helped a lot. Thank you @itminus for your nice answer!

Comment: @AminM I don't know why someone downvotes. I think it's "a question that is useful and clear". So I decide to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way, just write in ts:

```
(window as any).DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('some', 'some');
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like microsoft has released an official npm package:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop

Installing that package and importing it:

`import {DotNet} from "@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop";`

allows me to use `DotNet.DotNetObject` from Typescript.